# Android Google maps is not working probably

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello I am using google maps v2 in my app i tested offline map in the company(3rd floor) it works fine but in the street it doesn't show my location it works fine in my home too (4th floor)
here the map code:

```
mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
requestPermission();

createLocationRequest();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

here is the createLocationRequest method:

```
  mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 60 * 1);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 60 * 1);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting an accurate point you can use this. The same problem I faced when I had developed a monitoring application. Using this code I able to solve my problem.

http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java

```
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
```